# what is the difference between const [a, b, c] = array; and const {a, b, c} = array;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

```
const [a, b, c] = array; 

const {a, b, c} = array;
```

Q: what is the difference here in both the statements?

Comment: The first one is array destructuring and the second one is object destructuring.

Comment: [Destructuring assignment - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 17):

The first is *iterable destructuring*. `a` will get the first value in `array`, `b` will get the second, and `c` will get the third.

The second is *object destructuring*. `a` will get the value of `array.a`, `b` will get the value of `array.b`, and `c` will get the value of `array.c`. (Not usually what you want with arrays.)

Example of the first:

```js
const [a, b, c] = ["ay", "bee", "see"];
console.log(a, b, c);
```

That example uses an array, but the source can be any iterable object.

Example of the second (object destructuring), with an array:

```js
const array = ["ay", "bee", "see"];
const {a, b, c} = array;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

In the normal case, of course, those will all be `undefined` (as they are above), because arrays don't normally have those properties.

Example of the second (object destructuring), with a non-array object:

```js
const obj = {a: "ayy", b: "bee", c: "see"};
const {a, b, c} = obj;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

You don't normally use object destructuring with arrays, although you can, since arrays are objects. The times it's useful are when you want to pick out specific entries from the array, such as this code picking out the values at indexes 2 and 4:

```js
const array = ["ay", "bee", "see", "dee", "eee"];
const {2: c, 4: e} = array;
console.log(c, e); // "see" "eee"
```

You can even do that with indexes from a variable using computed property notation in the destructuring pattern:

```js
const array = ["ay", "bee", "see", "dee", "eee"];
const indexA = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
const indexB = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
const {[indexA]: a, [indexB]: b} = array;
console.log(`${indexA}: ${a}, ${indexB}: ${b}`); // Varies depending on the random indexes
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: FWIW, I cover destructuring thoroughly in my new book in Chapter 7 (see my profile for links).

Comment: @MuratKaragöz - Heh, tempting. :-) But I figured I should stick close to the OP's code...

Answer (score 2):

These are array de-structuring and object de-structuring in ES6 Javascript.

To demonstrate with example,

```
const [a, b, c] = [10, 11, 12];
From the above array destructuring statement: 
a, b and c are the variables declared and intialized with 10, 11 and 12 values respectively.
```

```
const person = {
  first: 'abc',
  last: 'def',
};
const {first, last} = person;
From the above object destructuring statement, 
first and last are varialbes declared and initialised with 'abc' and 'def' respectively.

The variable first and second accessed (gets the value) like person.first and person.last respectively
```

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring), it assigns array elements (`array[0]`, etc) to respective variables. It's applicable only to iterables, which arrays are:

```
const array = [0, 1];
const [a, b] = array;
// a === 0; 
// b === 1;
```

Example 2 is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), it assigns object key values to respective variables. Since an array is an object in JS, `const {a, b} = ...` object destructuring is applicable to an array only if it has non-numeric keys:

```
const array = [0, 1];
array.a = 'a';
array.b = 'b';    
const {a, b} = array;
// a === 'a'; 
// b === 'b';
```

Object destructuring can in fact be used to destructure arrays because they are objects that consist of numeric keys:

```
const array = [0, 1];
const {0: a, 1: b} = array;
// a === 0; 
// b === 1;
```

Comment: *"...object destructuring is applicable to an array only if it has non-numeric keys..."* Well, no, as you show later in the answer...

Comment: I meant the exact `const {a, b}` destructuring as the OP showed. Thanks for the remark.